# Applying Rigidbody force to Unity components

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui, unity-components

I have a NGUI sprite, NGUI label and Rigidbody component attached to my gameobject. When I apply force to the rigidbody of my gameobject, only one of the components is affected. If I have both the components enabled, then force is applied to the sprite and if I disable the sprite, then force is applied to the label component. I need the force to get applied to all the components within the gameobject which has a rigidbody. What am i doing wrong or missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I put the sprite and label components in separate gameobjects and attached them to another container which has a rigidbody.
This solved the problem.